# Why is "Run > Run with Performance Tool > Shark" always gray in Xcode? How to call that?

Tags: iphone, xcode, shark

There's this Shark entry in my run menu. But it's always inactive. What's wrong? New xcode with Snow Leopard. Installed all developer tools including CHUD from scratch. Shark itself runs but sees no devices, even though xcode does. it builds and runs on the device. no issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the same issue when working in iPhone Apps.  For MAC Apps it is not greyed out on Snow Leopard for me at least.

So... I suggest build and run your application, then find the Shark Application  and launch it manually.

Here is a quick guide I found useful.

http://rudifa.wordpress.com/2009/09/16/profiling-an-iphone-application-with-shark/

Good luck!

Kevin

Comment: And a +1 for you; I'll admit to not looking <b>too</b> hard, but I've been wondering how to enable this.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the "real" answer, there are a number of things XCode greys out that are OK to run.  You can for example launch Instruments manually and attach to your app to run other instruments XCode would not let you start with, Shark as noted is the same way.